# Move title & ratings above image gallery on mobile devices in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to move my title and ratings above the image gallery in woocommerce but only on mobile. **Desktop version should remain the same.**

I found a `php` code that i pasted in my theme's `functions.php` and it does the job but it moves them above on desktop as well.

Any way to run this `php` code only on mobile?

```php
function product_change_title_position() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'product_change_title_position' );

function product_change_rating_position() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 5 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'product_change_rating_position' );
```

Thanks
Vaibhav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress provides a function called [`wp_is_mobile`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/), which allows you to do what you're looking for:

```php
add_action('init', 'product_change_title_position');

function product_change_title_position()
{
    if (wp_is_mobile()) 
    {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
        add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
    }
}

add_action('init', 'product_change_rating_position');

function product_change_rating_position()
{
    if (wp_is_mobile()) 
    {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10);
        add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 5);
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- *"It works through the detection of the browser user agent string ($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’])."*
- *"This function will return true for a tablet, as it too is considered a mobile device. It is not a substitute for CSS media queries or styling per platform."*